# Masking Amazon S3 mp3 file url and html5 mobile audio issues

Tags: php, html, audio, amazon-s3

I am using `amazon s3` server to serve mp3 files to users. However, to control usage of these mp3 files and protect real `s3` url I am using a php file to mask the url. Following is the code I use:

```
$audioName = $_GET['p'];
require_once 'class/S3.php';

$expires = 60*60*24*30;

header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=".$expires.", pre-check=".$expires);
header("Expires: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');

$getPhoto = new S3(access key, secret access key);
$response = S3::getObject('bucketname', $audioName);

header('Content-Type: ' . $response->headers['type']);
header('Content-Length: ' . $response->headers['size']);
echo $response->body;
```

Then on my html side I use a simple audio tag to play this file:

```
<audio controls preload="none">
<source src="audiofile.php?id=1" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Preload is set to none because I want to start downloading mp3 file only after the user presses play.

Now the issue is (especially mobile browsers, mostly chrome mobile browser), when a user presses play it takes quite some time (around 8-10secs) before the mp3 actually starts playing. This happens every time, regardless of the cache-control that I have set.

P.S.: I use this amazon s3 class from undesigned: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are downloading the whole file to your server before turning around and serving the file. Your users will have to wait for the whole file to be downloaded to your server and then for enough of it to download to their machines before it can start playing while a direct link to S3 would allow the user to prog